# Read a Azure Blob via c# and insert into on-premise SQL Server

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, azure-blob-storage

This is a Proof Of Concept.
Goal: Read a Azure Blob and load it into a on-premise SQL server.

Steps:
Using C# I have connected and downloaded the Azure blob into a Memory Stream, and parsed it into a Json file.
I am planning to using EntityFramework to load the data into the on-premise SQL server.

AzureBlob --> MemoryStream --> Json file --> List of Class Object --> Use EntityFramework to load to SQL via MVC

Could anyone let me know if this is the right approach or suggest anything better?

Thank you

Comment: "I am planning to using EntityFramework " - might be heavyweight, try Dapper instead.

Comment: you can't use the platform solution Azure File Sync ?

Comment: This isn't a good question for Stack Overflow. We aren't here to answer primarily opinion based questions. Instead, try to implement your goal. If you get stuck, provide a [mcve] and clearly explain what's not working properly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could skip the

> Json file --> List of Class Object --> Use EntityFramework

steps and parse the json in a stored procedure and then insert it into a table.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[JsonTest] (
    [Id]          INT           NOT NULL,
    [firstName]   NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
    [lastName]    NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
    [age]         INT           NULL,
    [dateOfBirth] DATETIME2 (7) NULL
);

DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @json = N'[
     {"id": 2, "info": {"name": "John", "surname": "Smith"}, "age": 25},
     {"id": 5, "info": {"name": "Jane", "surname": "Smith"}, "dob": "2005-11-04T12:00:00"}
]';

INSERT INTO JsonTest 
SELECT *
FROM OPENJSON(@json)
   WITH (
     id INT 'strict $.id',
     firstName NVARCHAR(50) '$.info.name',
     lastName NVARCHAR(50) '$.info.surname',
     age INT,
     dateOfBirth DATETIME2 '$.dob'
  );

SELECT * FROM JsonTest
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15#convert-json-collections-to-a-rowset

For something like this I would also suggest using Dapper.